# How to get rid of these underlined things in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I type any HTML code in Visual Studio Code these items underline automatically which make code very illegible. I was looking for some solution but I haven't find anything useful.

Here's the example:
[image: Here's the example]

Comment: if you Ctrl+Click such a link that file will be opened, images too

Comment: Per your clarification, look at the `Editor: Match Brackets` setting.

Comment: Thank you Mark, that solved my problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

go to **Files > Preferences > Settings** in your VSCode
then search for **editor.links** in your settings search bar, uncheck the option **Editor: links**  and thats it

Comment: is there a similar setting for types? in typescript react `React.FC` is underlined also